# How to delete items without reload or refresh page in ionic 4?

Tags: java, angular, ionic-framework

I have list of notification, user can select list of notification and delete.

Delete process working fine but I have to reload page every time user delete item, I couldn't view the changes once user delete elements.

I have trying Angular detect changes but it doesn't work.

It looks like there is something prevent Angular functions from work.

**My .ts page**

```
   async changeView(){
       if(this.dataselect!=undefined){
           if(this.dataselect!=""){
             const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
              message: this.removenoti,
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: "Cancel",
                  role: 'cancel',
                  handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                  }
                }, {
                  text: "Remove",
                  handler: () => {
                    const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
                    this.userData.id = SigninData.mem_id;
                    this.userData.token  = SigninData.token;
                    this.userData.noti_id = this.dataselect;
                    console.log(this.userData.noti_id);

                    this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "deletenoti2").subscribe((result) =>{
                        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => { 

                        this.presentToast(this.removesuccess);

                        // executing inside NgZone 
                        this.zone.run(() => {
                            this.dataselect="";
                            this.edit=false;
                            this.SelAll = false;
                            for(var i in this.items)
                            {
                                this.checkItems[this.items[i].id]=false;
                            }
                        });
                        console.log(result);
                        
                        let loading_time = 2000;
                        setTimeout( () => {
                            this.ngOnInit();
                        }, loading_time);
                    //  window.location.assign('/');
                    });

                    }, (err) => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                        this.presentToast("Please connect your device to internet!");
                    });

                  }
                }
              ]
            });
            await alert.present();
        } else {
           this.presentToast(this.noitems);
        }
       } else {
           this.presentToast(this.noitems);
       }
    }
```

**My html code**

```
<ion-content style="--padding-top:6em">
    <ion-fab *ngIf="exist=='true'" class="header_tab">
        <button ion-fab *ngIf="edit" class="cancelremove" style="right: 45px;" (click)="changeView()">
            <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
     </ion-fab>

    <div *ngIf="exist=='true'">

        <ion-grid *ngFor="let item of items" class="list" >
          <ion-row class="textin" *ngIf="item.nstatus!=1" [style.background-color]="hexColor2">

                <ion-checkbox *ngIf="edit" [checked]="allSelected" [(ngModel)]="checkItems[item.id]" (ionChange)="DeSelect();DeSelectall(item.id)"></ion-checkbox>

                <ion-label style="width: 100%;max-height: 4em;">
                    <ion-col col-12 (click)="view(item.id, item.nsubject, item.ndetail, item.ncompany, item.nphoto)">
                        <ion-row class="condate">
                            <ion-col col-7 style="padding-left:0;">
                            <div *ngIf="item.nid!=0">
                                <p class="titlenote">{{ item.ncompany}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="item.nid==0">
                                <p class="titlenote">Tagy</p>
                            </div>
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col col-5>
                                <p class="date">{{ item.ndate| date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm' }}</p>
                            </ion-col>
                        </ion-row>
                        <ion-row>
                            <ion-col col-12>
                                <p class="detailnote">{{ item.nsubject }}</p>
                            </ion-col>
                        </ion-row>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-label>
          </ion-row>

        </ion-grid>
    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't it because you have `this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {` in your code?

Comment: I have tried delete this line but still the same issue.

Comment: I am not that good at reading other peoples code, but if i am correct, you are deleting an item from a list of items, and want your view to represent the new state of listed items. Normally there are no issues with a task like that, but you could either: Call your "fetch items" function again? Or have a local state of listed items you use for your ngFor loop where you remove the item from? Angular normally detects changes just fine (unless you mess with ViewEncapsulation).

Comment: Angular not detect changes in the whole page. Do I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you can use Observables and Behavior Subjects.
You can create them like this in the .ts file

```
activityLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
this.activityLoaded$.next(true);
```

and use them with the async pipe in the html

```html
*ngIf="(activityLoaded$ | async) === false"
```

As it is async, it will update itself everytime a new value will be pushed with .next method.

I'm sorry I don't have the time to perfectly adapt my answer to your question but now you at least know and can learn more about it.

Here is a 1st link on the subject:
https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing this kind of issue when I worked with Ionic for my mobile project. After fetching data from an API, to re-render the UI, we had to execute the code within `NgZone` for angular to call change detection. So try this inside your `handler: ()` function:

```
this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "deletenoti2").subscribe((result) => {

   this.presentToast(this.removesuccess);
   
   // executing inside NgZone 
   this.zone.run(() => {
     this.dataselect="";
     this.edit=false;
     this.SelAll = false;

     for(var i in this.items) {
        this.checkItems[this.items[i].id]=false;
     }
   });
   
   console.log(result);
}
```

As I do not have full visibility of your component's code, above code is my best assumption what should execute inside NgZone, based on the code sample you have provided.

Of course, to use `NgZone`, you have to import it and declare in the constructor:

```
constructor(
  ...
  ...
  private zone: NgZone
) {}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just try your code. It doesn't work, it looks like something prevent Angular from work.

Comment: Is it because I'm using ```await``` in the code?

Comment: It's hard to tell just looking at your code. You should create stackblitz to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **ChangeDetectorRef** to ask angular to detect any changes.

example:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

deleteItem() {
 this.cdr.markForCheck();
 this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```